# reading the value in an input tag in a html table using java script

Tags: javascript, html

```
<table id="myTable" style="border: 1px solid; border-color: black; border-collapse: collapse;">
    <thead  style="background-color: silver;">
        <tr>
            <th >1</th>
            <th >2</th>
            <th >3</th>
            <th >4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody  id="my_form">
        <tr>
            <td > <input type="text"> </td>
            <td > <input type="text"></td>
            <td ><input type="text"> </td>
            <td ><input  type="text"> </td>
        </tr>               
    </tbody>
</table>
```

this is my html table and this is my js function to read it's contents

```
var mytable=document.getElementById('myTable');
var row_length=myTable.rows.length;
for(var i=1;i<row_length;i++)
    {
        var cells=change_key_table.rows.item(i).cells;
        var cell_length=cells.length;
        var content = cells.item(0).innerText;
            alert(content);
    }
```

this gives a blank string. `innerText` should not be used to read the value from the table? is there any specific method to read value from input tags? i read a lot of question in stack overflow regarding this but could find anything to solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> innerText should not be used to read the value from the table?

It can't be used to read the value from an input.

> is there any specific method to read value from input tags?

Method? No. You need to access the `value` property of the input (which will be a string).

You can bypass dealing with the table structure entirely as it doesn't seem to be doing anything significant.

```
var mytable = document.getElementById('myTable');
var myinputs = mytable.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < myinputs.length; i++) {
    alert(myinputs[i].value);
}
```